# Watch for file changes in Linux

Tags: performance, bash, linux

I have installed [Geekworm x735](https://wiki.geekworm.com/X735) on my Raspberry Pi, it uses the script below with an infinite loop to determine if the power button has been pressed. I know there are some Linux utils that watch for file changes (inotifywait, watch, fswatch to name a few), I wonder if they are more efficient than this solution or if under the hood they apply the same logic.

```html
while [ 1 ]; do
  shutdownSignal=$(cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio$SHUTDOWN/value)
  if [ $shutdownSignal = 0 ]; then
    /bin/sleep 0.2
  else
    pulseStart=$(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13)
    while [ $shutdownSignal = 1 ]; do
      /bin/sleep 0.02
      if [ $(($(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13)-$pulseStart)) -gt $REBOOTPULSEMAXIMUM ]; then
        echo "X735 Shutting down", SHUTDOWN, ", halting Rpi ..."
        sudo poweroff
        exit
      fi
      shutdownSignal=$(cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio$SHUTDOWN/value)
    done
    if [ $(($(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13)-$pulseStart)) -gt $REBOOTPULSEMINIMUM ]; then 
      echo "X735 Rebooting", SHUTDOWN, ", recycling Rpi ..."
      sudo reboot
      exit
    fi
  fi
```

Thank you.

Comment: That's not really a code review question. You could find out how they work by looking at the sources. Shortly: They don't work this way but use Linux-specific notification mechanisms which only act on change, they don't permanently poll for changes.

Comment: Thank you Uli, that's all I wanted to know. I'd like to close the question but apparently I can't?

Comment: I have used triggerhappy on other Linux SBCs to handle buttons, wouldn't it be a better option perhaps ?

Answer (score 1):

Polling like this is a very inefficient mechanism, but for pseudo-files in `/sys/`, you may find that the usual kernel interfaces as used by `inotifywait` and the like don't get notified of changes in the same way that they do for real storage-backed files.  So it may be that you need to poll, unfortunately.  But do check, for the files you care about.

There doesn't seem to be any value creating `shutdownSignal` to immediately use - simpler to just insert the value directly:

```
while [ $(</sys/class/gpio/gpio$SHUTDOWN/value) = 1 ]
```

`sudo` is intended for interactive use, and doesn't work well in scripts.  I think it's better to assume (or check) that the script is invoked with sufficient capabilities to do the work it needs to do.

Don't forget to add a shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`).

Comment: Thank you Toby, it turns out that "watch" command works well with /sys folder.

Comment: @Oriol, `watch` works by polling, so yes, it will work with files that don't implement notification.